# Detect the specific iPhone/iPod touch model

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, p2p, device

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determine device (iPhone, iPod Touch) with iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448162/determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-ios)

I am making a game that utilizes the peer-to-peer bluetooth capabilities of the iPhone (and probably the iPod touch 2nd generation). However, to stop the users from trying to play a multiplayer on an iPod 1st gen and iPhone 2G I need to check for the specific device model.

[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] will only tell me if the device is an "iPhone" or an "iPod touch". Is there a way to check for the specific device model, like: "iPhone 3GS", "iPod touch 1st generation" or something.

**EDIT:**

There is a category to UIDevice (I think it's created by Erica Sadun, I don't take credit for it) that uses the following code to get the specific device model. You can find the whole category here along with other useful stuff: https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

@implementation UIDevice (Hardware)

/*
 Platforms
 iPhone1,1 -> iPhone 1G
 iPhone1,2 -> iPhone 3G 
 iPod1,1   -> iPod touch 1G 
 iPod2,1   -> iPod touch 2G 
*/

- (NSString *) platform
{
  size_t size;
  sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
  char *machine = malloc(size);
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size, NULL, 0);
    NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithCString:machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  free(machine);
  return platform;
}
```

This works and apps using this have been lately approved in the AppStore.

Comment: In <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/786026/how-do-you-detect-iphone-v-iphone-3g-using-obj-c">this</a> SO question, a link was posted to <a href="http://github.com/ars/uidevice-extension/tree/master">this</a> website. HTH

Comment: VERY IMPORTANT: Apple recommends NOT to use this code. This is because in some scenarios this can be detected incorrectly.

Check WWDC 2011 Session 123 at 3'30 and you'll see them showing this exact code and telling not to use.

Comment: @Lookez and what code we have to use?

Comment: I saw that video. Using that kind of code is not recommended for checking for iPad (as we have UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM for it now), but nothing was said about using it to determine the concrete hardware model.

Comment: Yea its not that in "some scenarios this can be detected incorrectly", it is always detected correctly. You just have to future proof your code and not have some dangling "else" condition that defaults to a specific version.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Most complete UIDevice (Hardware) category probably is http://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension/ (by Erica Sadun):

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] platformType]   // ex: UIDevice4GiPhone
[[UIDevice currentDevice] platformString] // ex: @"iPhone 4G"
```

Comment: It is not working today. I can't find platformType and platformString in [UIDevice currentDevice].

Comment: @RobertYiJiang did you add the classes from the Github project linked in the answer?

Answer (score 154):

You can get the device model number using `uname` from `sys/utsname.h`. For example:

```
#import <sys/utsname.h>

NSString*
machineName()
{
    struct utsname systemInfo;
    uname(&systemInfo);

    return [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine
                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

The result should be:

```
@"i386"      on the simulator
@"iPod1,1"   on iPod Touch
@"iPod2,1"   on iPod Touch Second Generation
@"iPod3,1"   on iPod Touch Third Generation
@"iPod4,1"   on iPod Touch Fourth Generation
@"iPhone1,1" on iPhone
@"iPhone1,2" on iPhone 3G
@"iPhone2,1" on iPhone 3GS
@"iPad1,1"   on iPad
@"iPad2,1"   on iPad 2
@"iPad3,1"   on iPad 3 (aka new iPad)
@"iPhone3,1" on iPhone 4
@"iPhone4,1" on iPhone 4S
@"iPhone5,1" on iPhone 5
@"iPhone5,2" on iPhone 5
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That did it!
Just a correction: iPhone 3GS is "iPhone2,1".

Cheers

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the answer with the result for iPhone 3GS.

Comment: What is the systemInfo for iPhone 2 gen? Is it the same as iPhone 3G?

Comment: @iPhoney The original 2G iPhone is @"iPhone1,1".

Comment: Anyone know what all of the new devices spit out?  iPad? iPod Touch 2010?

Comment: @jtalarico I've added the string for iPad. I don't have access to an iPod Touch 2010.

Comment: I've added iPad 2, iPhone 4S, and some newer iPods Touch. I don't have these devices to hand, so the strings are based on hearsay rather than direct evidence, but they come from a reliable-sounding source.

Comment: whether apple will allow to use this code??

Comment: @"x86_64" for simulator.

Comment: I'm not sure if it was me or what, but this worked for me in development when I tested on 4,4s,and 5, but it failed hard in production and didn't seem to work at all which caused lots of problems.

Comment: @"Dave Chenell", isn't it that in production [NSString stringWithCString] uses wrong encoding? Because it may change by environment and therefore return nil.

Comment: 6 plus: iPhone7,1
6: iPhone7,2
5S: iPhone6,2

Comment: This coding is crashing when building in Xcode 7.3 on iPhone 4-devices exclusively.

Comment: @RenishDadhaniya your edit completely changes this answer.  I have rolled it back.  If you have a new answer in Swift, you should add it as your own answer, not change an existing answer.

Comment: @JAL, Yes i will take care.I will upload as a new answer because older answer in not working in all iOS7+ versions in swift. Thank You!

Answer (score 23):

How about this code, if new version was released, you will identifier with the last know device

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

- (NSString *)getModel {
    size_t size;
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
    char *model = malloc(size);
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", model, &size, NULL, 0);
    NSString *sDeviceModel = [NSString stringWithCString:model encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    free(model);                              
    if ([sDeviceModel isEqual:@"i386"])      return @"Simulator";  //iPhone Simulator
    if ([sDeviceModel isEqual:@"iPhone1,1"]) return @"iPhone1G";   //iPhone 1G
    if ([sDeviceModel isEqual:@"iPhone1,2"]) return @"iPhone3G";   //iPhone 3G
    if ([sDeviceModel isEqual:@"iPhone2,1"]) return @"iPhone3GS";  //iPhone 3GS
    if ([sDeviceModel isEqual:@"iPhone3,1"]) return @"iPhone4 AT&T";  //iPhone 4 - AT&T
    if ([sDeviceModel isEqual:@"iPhone3,2"]) return @"iPhone4 Other";  //iPhone 4 - Other carrier
    if ([sDeviceModel isEqual:@"iPhone3,3"]) return @"iPhone4";    //iPhone 4 - Other carrier
    if ([sDeviceModel isEqual:@"iPhone4,1"]) return @"iPhone4S";   //iPhone 4S
    if ([sDeviceModel isEqual:@"iPhone5,1"]) return @"iPhone5";    //iPhone 5 (GSM)
    if ([sDeviceModel isEqual:@"iPod1,1"])   return @"iPod1stGen"; //iPod Touch 1G
    if ([sDeviceModel isEqual:@"iPod2,1"])   return @"iPod2ndGen"; //iPod Touch 2G
    if ([sDeviceModel isEqual:@"iPod3,1"])   return @"iPod3rdGen"; //iPod Touch 3G
    if ([sDeviceModel isEqual:@"iPod4,1"])   return @"iPod4thGen"; //iPod Touch 4G
    if ([sDeviceModel isEqual:@"iPad1,1"])   return @"iPadWiFi";   //iPad Wifi
    if ([sDeviceModel isEqual:@"iPad1,2"])   return @"iPad3G";     //iPad 3G
    if ([sDeviceModel isEqual:@"iPad2,1"])   return @"iPad2";      //iPad 2 (WiFi)
    if ([sDeviceModel isEqual:@"iPad2,2"])   return @"iPad2";      //iPad 2 (GSM)
    if ([sDeviceModel isEqual:@"iPad2,3"])   return @"iPad2";      //iPad 2 (CDMA)

    NSString *aux = [[sDeviceModel componentsSeparatedByString:@","] objectAtIndex:0];

//If a newer version exist
    if ([aux rangeOfString:@"iPhone"].location!=NSNotFound) {
        int version = [[aux stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"iPhone" withString:@""] intValue];
        if (version == 3) return @"iPhone4"
        if (version >= 4) return @"iPhone4s";

    }
    if ([aux rangeOfString:@"iPod"].location!=NSNotFound) {
        int version = [[aux stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"iPod" withString:@""] intValue];
        if (version >=4) return @"iPod4thGen";
    }
    if ([aux rangeOfString:@"iPad"].location!=NSNotFound) {
        int version = [[aux stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"iPad" withString:@""] intValue];
        if (version ==1) return @"iPad3G";
        if (version >=2) return @"iPad2";
    }
    //If none was found, send the original string
    return sDeviceModel;
}
```

Comment: It still works! you need to add 
`#include <sys/types.h>
 #include <sys/sysctl.h>`

Comment: not working an getting output as  x86_64

Answer (score 4):

```
BOOL hasHighResScreen = NO;
if ([UIScreen instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
    CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
    if (scale > 1.0) {
        hasHighResScreen = YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesnt return the exact model. Only is it's got an "HD" or "SD" screen.

Comment: This was perfect for me. All I needed to know if the device has high res or not

Answer (score 4):

iPhone 4 is iPhone3,1 and iPhone3,2
iPhone 4S is iPhone4,1 
iPad 2 is iPad2,1 iPad2,2 and iPad2,3 depending on version (GSM etc)
iPad 3 is iPad3,1 iPad3,2 and iPad3,3 depending on version (GSM etc)

See [Iphone secrets](http://www.edepot.com/iphone.html) (scroll down to "internal product codes")

Another good source is:
[everyiphone.com](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/iphone/index-iphone-specs.html)

Answer (score -11):

```
NSString* valueDevice = [[UIDevice currentDevice] model];
```

and then check if the string is equal to whatever device you are looking for like :

```
if(value==@"iPod1,1" ) 
{}
```

and you should be good to go

Comment: Would be nice if people mentioned why this has -11 on it but no comment saying why.

Comment: The code `[[UIDevice currentDevice] model]` just returns "iPhone" or "iPad" not a model number.