# Check if iPhone 4 or not

Tags: iphone, xcode

I would like to check if the user is using an iPhone 4 or not. How can I do that ?

Thanks !
Sebastian

Comment: This same question was asked and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108859/detect-the-specific-iphone-ipod-touch-model

Although, as Jared P says, Apple recommends checking for features.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Apple specifically recommends against this, instead preferring that you check for individual features and act according to these.  This makes your life a lot easier when Apple releases new hardware; if for instance Apple releases an iPod Touch with a camera, and you need a camera for your app, your users wont be upset that it tells them "No camera found" when it does have one, all because it reports as not an iPhone.  [Here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW10) is one way to require all the differentiating hardware features.  Do not use these for enabling/disabling features that are supported but not required: this can be determined at runtime through the APIs used to interact with that feature.

UIDevice (see [here](http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/2010/05/how-to-uniquely-identify-your-users-iphone-ipad-or-ipod-with-uidevice/), also the docs) can help you determine if it is an iPhone, but again, don't do this.

Answer (score 0):

To detect the difference between the iPod Touch and the iPhone, we use

```
if(![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
```

There might be something similar to check for a the forward camera.

Comment: +1. Checking for the forward-facing camera is a decent option to determine if the hardware is iPhone 4+. Indeed it will eval to true when another device has a front camera as well - iPad or iPod Touch.