# How can I identify the particular iOS device is an iPhone 3G or an iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone, device, ipod

How can I identify if the iOS device my app runs on is an iPhone 3G of an iPhone 4?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This has been asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108859/detect-the-specific-iphone-ipod-touch-model) and a good answer seems to be provided.

Comment: BTW as a rule of thumb in most cases you don't need to know this... Unless your're making a game or something that's very special.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [uidevice-extension](http://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension/) by [Erica Sadon](http://github.com/erica).

You can use the following:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] platformType];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] platformString];
```