# iPhone/iPad/iPod model version

Tags: iphone, ios, model, version

For some reason, I need to know the model version of the device running my app.
I don't need to know the version of iOS running on the device, but the version of the device, for example : "iPhone 3G", "iPhone 4S", "iPad 2", ...

It doesn't seem that the UIDevice class gives this info :
    Identifying the Device and Operating System
        name  property
        systemName  property
        systemVersion  property
        model  property
        localizedModel  property
        userInterfaceIdiom  property
        uniqueIdentifier  property Deprecated in iOS 5.0

Did I miss anything ?

Thanks

Comment: You missed searching for this question..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108859/detect-the-specific-iphone-ipod-touch-model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [UIDevice-Extension](https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension/):

> Add functionality to UIDevice to distinguish between platforms like iPod touch 1G and 2G and iPhone

with the `UIDevice-Hardware.h` Class its possible to get the:

```
- (NSString *) platform;
- (NSString *) hwmodel;
- (NSUInteger) platformType;
- (NSString *) platformString;
```