# Is this a Facebook for iOS WebView User Agent?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, ipad, webkit

I'm looking through some logs trying to explain some "interesting" behavior and I'm seeing some users come to my application with a user agent similar to this one:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU iPhone OS 5_1_1 like Mac OS X; en_US) AppleWebKit (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile [FBAN/FBForIPhone;FBAV/4.1.1;FBBV/4110.0;FBDV/iPad2,1;FBMD/iPad;FBSN/iPhone OS;FBSV/5.1.1;FBSS/1; FBCR/;FBID/tablet;FBLC/en_US;FBSF/1.0]
```

If I run this string through [udger.com](https://udger.com/resources/online-parser?Fuas=Mozilla%2F5.0+%28iPad%3B+U%3B+CPU+iPhone+OS+5_1_1+like+Mac+OS+X%3B+en_US%29+AppleWebKit+%28KHTML%2C+like+Gecko%29+Mobile+%5BFBAN%2FFBForIPhone%3BFBAV%2F4.1.1%3BFBBV%2F4110.0%3BFBDV%2FiPad2%2C1%3BFBMD%2FiPad%3BFBSN%2FiPhone+OS%3BFBSV%2F5.1.1%3BFBSS%2F1%3B+FBCR%2F%3BFBID%2Ftablet%3BFBLC%2Fen_US%3BFBSF%2F1.0%5D%0D%0A&test=&action=analyze) I get the following result:

[image: user agent screenshot]

This screen shot and user agent confuses me because it says it's the mobile safari for iPod and iPad.  I see `iPad` in the first part of the user-agent, but I also see a lot of references to FB and iPhone and iOS and all kinds of other things.

I'm curious if this is a "generic" user-agent that is served up by the Facebook for iOS application, and if it is - is the device an iPad or is it just not clear enough to tell?

Comment: I can't be sure (hence comment instead of answer), but that looks like users accessing your site from a webview inside the Facebook for iOS app

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes it is the iOS Facebook app....

The following is the user agent string from an iPhone 4s showing that it includes the correct device `iPhone4,1`

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0_1 like Mac OS X)
AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/10A523
[FBAN/FBIOS;FBAV/5.3;FBBV/89182;FBDV/iPhone4,1;FBMD/iPhone;FBSN/iPhoneOS;
FBSV/6.0.1;FBSS/2; FBCR/O2;FBID/phone;FBLC/en_US]
```

The devices shown seem to follow the same model identification shown in an answer on [detecting iOS models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108859/detect-the-specific-iphone-ipod-touch-model)

```
@"i386"      on the simulator
@"iPod1,1"   on iPod Touch
@"iPod2,1"   on iPod Touch Second Generation
@"iPod3,1"   on iPod Touch Third Generation
@"iPod4,1"   on iPod Touch Fourth Generation
@"iPhone1,1" on iPhone
@"iPhone1,2" on iPhone 3G
@"iPhone2,1" on iPhone 3GS
@"iPad1,1"   on iPad
@"iPad2,1"   on iPad 2
@"iPad3,1"   on iPad 3 (aka new iPad)
@"iPhone3,1" on iPhone 4
@"iPhone4,1" on iPhone 4S
@"iPhone5,1" on iPhone 5
@"iPhone5,2" on iPhone 5
```

**This means the string you show that it was an the facebook app on [iPad 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPad_2)**