# Detect Facebook Mobile Browser

Tags: javascript, php, facebook

Is it somehow possible to detect Facebook's mobiles apps' browser via PHP or JS?
My apps all have problems inside their browser (in native browser not!) and I want to show a warning notice.

Alternatively, is there a possibility to directly open the website in a external browser?

Comment: Detecting it by evaluating the `User-Agent` header is probably your best bet. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11414006/is-this-a-facebook-for-ios-webview-user-agent

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me in JavaScript:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/) && navigator.userAgent.match(/FBAV/i)) {
    //iOS Facebook App Browser detected
}
```

More information about the User Agent: [Is this a Facebook for iOS WebView User Agent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11414006/is-this-a-facebook-for-ios-webview-user-agent)

Afaik it´s not possible to force the website to open in any external browser, only the user can do that.