# Facebook mobile browser: New Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, hyperlink, tabs

I have an online quiz that at one point gives users the option to open a new link in the new tab. I have this set up of course with target=_blank. However I've been getting complaints that on Facebook/Instagram when the users click the link during the quiz it does not open in a new tab. This is a problem because it's a long quiz and they have to start over.

How do I get a link to open in a new tab in Facebook's web browser and or are there any alternatives?

Current set up:

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.mylink.com">Link</a>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible to have it open in a new tab within Facebook. However it is possible to detect when the user is using the Facebook browser and hide whatever you need to.

Info taken from this post: [Detect Facebook Mobile Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297601/detect-facebook-mobile-browser)

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/) && navigator.userAgent.match(/FBAV/i)) {
    //iOS Facebook App Browser detected
}
```