# iOS: images for 4inch display

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

How can i specify image name for image view in 4 inch display like for retina size @2x is using with image name? Is there any special way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no difference for the iPhone 5. It's retina so it uses the @2x images, but there's nothing specific apart from the Default-568h@2x.png image you use to tell the operating system you're supporting the larger screen.

The only difference between the 3.5 and 4 inch iPhone is the size that `[[UIWindow mainWindow] bounds]` (and related screen size elements) returns.

Comment: then should i need to increase the image height? for eg. Iam setting a background imageview which is having frame size (0,0,320,480). So if it in 4 inch display shall i change this frame size to (0,0,320,560) ?

Comment: What I've done is create conditional background-sizes depending on the   screen resolution. Check out these answers for some great information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396545/how-to-deal-with-iphone-5-screen-size

Answer (score 0):

@2x images are meant for retina display i.e. iPhone 4S as well as iPhone 5.

For selecting different images for iPhone 4S and iPhone 5, I first check which device model am I using the link:

[Detect the specific iPhone/iPod touch model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108859/detect-the-specific-iphone-ipod-touch-model)

Then accordingly you can set images for iPone 4S or iPhone 5....

Comment: A much better way is to use the screen/window size, detecting the device more than detecting iPad/iPhone is a fragile way to support multiple screen sizes.