# How to exactly detect iDevice model?

Tags: ios, xcode, model, uidevice

I want to detect what `iDevice` the user has and then put the `device name` in a `UILabel`. With the following code the App detects only the iPhone/iPad/iPod I like to have iPhone 4/iPod 3G/iPad 1G... or the exact names (iPhone 3.1/iPod 2.0/ iPad 2.4)...

here is my code:

```
iDevice.text = [UIDevice currentDevice]. localizedModel;
```

I tried this to

```
iDevice.text = [UIDevice currentDevice]. model;
```

but alleyways it sayes iPhone and i like iPhone 3.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108859/detect-the-specific-iphone-ipod-touch-model

Comment: I tried all of these but non of them worked for me:(

Comment: Did you check the accepted answer to my link? I've used that with some success in the past. "Most complete UIDevice (Hardware) category probably is http://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension/"

Comment: I exactly need this but I dont know hiw to use it whith a lable

Answer (score 2):

Ok so it sounds like the method you will want to use is to use the category created by Erica Sadun located at https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension/

Before I get into how to use it I'll pass on a bit of info about categories.  Apple provides documentation on categories here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html

> You can add methods to a class by declaring them in an interface file
>   under a category name and defining them in an implementation file
>   under the same name. The category name indicates that the methods are
>   additions to a class declared elsewhere, not a new class. You cannot,
>   however, use a category to add additional instance variables to a
>   class.

Download the project from github, and add these two files to your project:

```
UIDevice-Hardware.h
UIDevice-Hardware.m
```

The methods you'll be using would be one of these:

```
- (NSString *) platform;
- (NSString *) hwmodel;
- (NSUInteger) platformType;
- (NSString *) platformString;
```

So you'll want to import UIDevice-Hardware.h into the file where you want to use the method. You would use the method to return an NSString value and assign the value to a label, so you'd do something similar to

```
mylabel.text = [[UIDevice currentDevice] platformString]
```

Here's another link that has a good introduction to categories: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/objective-c-categories/

EDIT: SAMPLE SCREENSHOT USING THE DEVICE SIMULATOR:
[image]
Note: also have `#import "UIDevice-Hardware.h"` above my @interface line.

Comment: Now I added the UIDevice-Hardware.h and the UIDevice-Hardware.m to my project, i #import "UIDevice-Hardware.h" the file in my .m file, then I added the mylabel.text = [[UIDevice currentDevice] platformString]
to - (void)viewDidLoad and my app crashes:( What is my mistake? must i do anything with the                                                  - (NSString *) platform;
- (NSString *) hwmodel;
- (NSUInteger) platformType;
- (NSString *) platformString;?

Comment: for your instance you would want `iDevice.text = [[UIDevice currentDevice] platformString];`  That had just been a generic label namei wrote.  It was probably crashing because my variable name hadn't been defined.

Comment: I have iDevice.text = [[UIDevice currentDevice] platformString];

Comment: It is too difficult to describe so i made a picture:[link](http://www.mediafire.com/view/?dg7u30c89p1ck3a)

Comment: Could you create a postbin or gist of the code you're using?  I'm going to try to recreate this real quick.

Comment: I've added a screenshot using the category to my original response Let me know if you can log your device instead of doing the assignment to iDevice

Comment: When i add NSLog(@"Current Device: %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice]platformString]); in ViewDidLoad, my app crashes too:(

Comment: Could you please make a gist of the UIDevice-Hardware.h file.

Comment: I found this [link](https://github.com/eagle-dan1349/EDDeviceHardware)  on Web but I get 2 errors when I putt this in my project. You might could glimps on it if you like, I couldn't find the mistakes. When i try to install the project on my iDevice I works but i cant implement in in my project.

Comment: I looked at your error again.  Do you still see this same error?  It basically says `[UIDevice platformString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.`  So i'm wondering somewhere instead of `[[UIDevice currentDevice] platformString]` you have `[UIDevice platformString]` so that's the error.  It's tough to debug without seeing your whole project. This is a great resource for understanding how to debug xcode errors: http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: I checked everything and there is no [UIDevice platformString] but i have this in my project : float currentVersion = 6.0;
        
        if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= currentVersion) could this cose the problem?

Comment: It may be a bit slow I'd say the best way to check would be to comment out entire blocks of code, and slowly uncomment your code until you can isolate what's causing the issue.