# How to programmatically detect if the app is running on a device with performance >= 4S?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determine device (iPhone, iPod Touch) with iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448162/determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-iphone-sdk)
>   [Detect the specific iPhone/iPod touch model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108859/detect-the-specific-iphone-ipod-touch-model)

If an app has some features which require high hardware performance which look only good on iPhone 4S and higher, how can I detect wether or not it is an iPhone 4?

I know it is not a good idea to detect models. but better to detect capabilities. How can I safely check that it's a device with a performance >= iPhone 4S?

Comment: Since the hardware of iOS devices (probably) doesn't vary as much as e.g. browsers, it may be worth finding out the general wisdom on model detection vs feature detection for iOS programming. Model detection and blacklisting earlier models, may very well be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You want to check the device id, not the version of the iOS, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3365391/1648976).

Without using any libraries, you could also refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1108927/1648976).