# How to check the device is iPhone 5?

Tags: iphone, ios

How can I check if an application running on iPhone 5 or not and then do something?

Comment: Are you really checking for an iPhone 5 or do you need to check for the 4" screen currently used by both the iPhone 5 and 5th gen iPod touch? And what do you plan to do with this knowledge? The answers will help guide the best solution.

Comment: @ChrisLatta - I searched and I did not find so sorry but this is not duplicated then.

Comment: @CroiOS why is it not a duplicate?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're likely concerned with the window size, not the make/model, this will do:

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
if (screenRect.size.height == 568)
{
 // this is an iPhone 5+
}
```

Comment: missing info here. @property(nonatomic,readonly) CGRect  bounds;                // Bounds of entire screen in points
@property(nonatomic,readonly) CGRect  applicationFrame;      // Frame of application screen area in points (i.e. entire screen minus status bar if visible)

Comment: This is not always true, if in your application status bar is visible its height is 548. To have this always equal to 568 use [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]; instead.

Answer (score 18):

```
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
```

then in the code:

```
if (IS_IPHONE_5) { 
   //is iphone 5
}
```

Comment: As in the other discussion it is really not necessary to check with epsilon

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with checking screen resolution or you can do it with using:

```
#import "sys/utsname.h"
```

which give you identifier for each device. Just see my answer here: [recognize device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046338/best-way-to-detect-hardware-type-iphone4-or-iphone5/13046400#13046400)

Answer (score 3):

Using screen is fine.

```
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
#define IS_IPHONE_5 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.0f)
```

No epsilon check is required

Answer (score 0):

We can directly put this method in constant file and can use any where using define

```
#define ISIPHONE5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
#define HEIGHT (ISIPHONE5 ? 60:145)
```

Or can use

```
 #define IS_IPHONE5 (([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-568)?NO:YES)
```

We can also check IOS via below

```
#define IOS_OLDER_THAN_6 ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 6.0 )
#define IOS_NEWER_OR_EQUAL_TO_6 ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 6.0 )
```

Answer (score -11):

You can check your device's iOS version if is 6.0 then its a iPhone 5.....

Here's the code..

```
double osVersion = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] doubleValue];
NSLog(@"OSVersion: %f", osVersion);
if (osVersion == 6.0) 
{
  //Paste your code here.....
}
```

Comment: it's not true, also iPhone 4s or iPhone 4 or iphone 3gs have ios 6.0...

Comment: yes, and many iPads run on iOS6, and they are also not iPhone5 devices in a case of universal application.

Comment: I hope your day job != "iOS Development"

Comment: iOS version is different and iPhone device is different..

Comment: Deep, welcome to iPhone Development...