# Programmatically find out the marketed memory size of iOS devices

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Is there any way to programmatically (in Objective-C) find out the marketed total physical memory of an iOS devices (such as iPad 2 16G, 32G, 64G)? It looks like `UIDevice` related APIs (such as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108859/detect-the-specific-iphone-ipod-touch-model) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448162/determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-iphone-sdk)) do not give such information.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712527/how-to-detect-total-available-free-disk-space-on-the-iphone-ipad-device). You can get the device total space as well as the free space available.
It gives you the clear idea.

Comment: Is the total space always exactly as the marketed memory size? Say, if it is an iPad 2 16G, is the total space detected exactly 16*2^30 bytes? If it's not, is there any way to detect the **marketed** memory size?

Comment: above link also gives us the total space.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up rounding to the total memory to the closest increment of 8G.

Answer (score 2):

A little late to the party but if anyone still gets here, there you go:

This one gives you the memory size as marketed on the iOS device (16GB, 32GB, 64GB, 128GB...)

**Calculated using the method suggested by others and then rounded off to the nearest bigger power of 2.**

**Swift 3.0 version**

```
extension UIDevice {

var marketedMemorySize: Int {

    do {
        let systemAttributes = try FileManager.default.attributesOfFileSystem(forPath: NSHomeDirectory() as String)
        let totalDiskSpaceInBytes = (systemAttributes[FileAttributeKey.systemSize] as? NSNumber)?.int64Value

        func formatter(_ bytes: Int64) -> String {
            let formatter = ByteCountFormatter()
            formatter.allowedUnits = ByteCountFormatter.Units.useGB
            formatter.countStyle = ByteCountFormatter.CountStyle.decimal
            formatter.includesUnit = false
            return formatter.string(fromByteCount: bytes) as String
        }

        if let bytes = totalDiskSpaceInBytes {
            let memory = formatter(bytes)

            if let floatMemory = Float(memory) {

                if floatMemory > 128 {
                    return 256
                } else if floatMemory > 64 {
                    return 128
                } else if floatMemory > 32 {
                    return 64
                } else if floatMemory > 16 {
                    return 32
                } else if floatMemory > 8 {
                    return 16
                } else if floatMemory > 4 {
                    return 8
                }

            }
        }
        return 0
    }
    catch {
        return 0
    }

}


}
```

**Use it like this:**

```
UIDevice.current.marketedMemorySize
```