# Determining the type of an iOS device in Xcode

Tags: ios

I want to access information regarding the device type in xcode to determine whether it is an iPhone 4, 4S, 5, an iPad etc.

Does anyone know a solution?

EDIT : this question is solved.
I'm using the following code from the answer below :

```
- (NSString *) IphoneModel {
    size_t size;
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
    char *machine = (char*)malloc(size);
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size, NULL, 0);
    NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithCString:machine encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    free(machine);

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"])    return @"iPhone 1G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"])    return @"iPhone 3G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"])    return @"iPhone 3GS";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"])    return @"iPhone 4";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,3"])    return @"Verizon iPhone 4";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"])    return @"iPhone 4S";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 1G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 2G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 3G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 4G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"])      return @"iPad";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,2"])      return @"iPad (3G)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"])      return @"iPad 2 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"])      return @"iPad 2 (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"])      return @"iPad 2 (CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,1"])      return @"iPad 3 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,2"])      return @"iPad 3 (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,3"])      return @"iPad 3 (CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"i386"])         return @"Simulator";

    return platform;
}
```

I know it's an insecure solution, but it will work for now until I am done with more crucial tasks.

Comment: Do you really want this information in Xcode (desktop IDE) or in an iOS app made using Xcode?

Comment: Question so many times asked. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108859/detect-the-specific-iphone-ipod-touch-model or use the device screen...

Comment: There is nothing to find as to which device you are using. Better go for the screen size and manipulate your views accordingly. Finding devices is a far approach and Apple doesn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (NSString *) IphoneModel {
    size_t size;
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
    char *machine = (char*)malloc(size);
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size, NULL, 0);
    NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithCString:machine encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    free(machine);

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"])    return @"iPhone 1G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"])    return @"iPhone 3G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"])    return @"iPhone 3GS";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"])    return @"iPhone 4";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,3"])    return @"Verizon iPhone 4";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"])    return @"iPhone 4S";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 1G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 2G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 3G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 4G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"])      return @"iPad";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,2"])      return @"iPad (3G)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"])      return @"iPad 2 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"])      return @"iPad 2 (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"])      return @"iPad 2 (CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,1"])      return @"iPad 3 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,2"])      return @"iPad 3 (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,3"])      return @"iPad 3 (CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"i386"])         return @"Simulator";

    return platform;
}
```

Comment: VERY IMPORTANT: Apple recommends NOT to use this code. This is because in some scenarios this can be detected incorrectly. Check WWDC 2011 Session 123 at 3'30 and you'll see them showing this exact code and telling not to use... Qouted from the question you took this from..... -_-