# Using different files for the same project on different devices in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

Say if I have 3 animation files for a size for iPhone 5s, iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus. What about ipad?

For the same view controller, how should I use these respective files for different iPhone sizes. Here's a specific example:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@”iphone5s” ofType:@”gif”];
```

but what if I want to load for iPhone 6, iPhone 6 plus called `iPhone6.gif`, `iPhone6Plus.gif` etc

I am using Objective-C.

Comment: Instead of detecting model, better go for screen resolution

Comment: All of my videos are 540 x 250 size and they are embedded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SDVersion](https://github.com/sebyddd/SDVersion) to detect the current `device` information . [SDVersion](https://github.com/sebyddd/SDVersion)  is :

#### Objective-C library for detecting the running device's model and screen size

So you can use it to get **device model** ,**device screen size**,**device name**,and **iOS Version** as follow:

```
  // Check for device model
  if ([SDVersion deviceVersion] == iPhone6)
       NSLog(@"You got the iPhone 6. Sweet !");
  else if ([SDVersion deviceVersion] == iPhone6Plus)
       NSLog(@"iPhone 6 Plus? Bigger is better!");
  else if ([SDVersion deviceVersion] == iPadAir2)
       NSLog(@"You own an iPad Air 2 !");

  // Check for device screen size
  if ([SDVersion deviceSize] == iPhone4inch)
       NSLog(@"Your screen is 4 inches");

  // Get device name
  NSLog(@"%@", stringFromDeviceVersion([SDVersion deviceName]));
  /* e.g: Outputs 'iPhone 6 Plus' */

  // Check for iOS Version
  if (iOSVersionGreaterThanOrEqual(@"8"))
       NSLog(@"You are running iOS 8 or above!");
```

In your situation ,  you can:

```
NSString *name;
DeviceSize size = [SDVersion deviceSize];

if (size == iPhone35inch)
    name = @"iPhone4";
else if(size == iPhone4inch)
    name = @"iPhone5";
else if(size == iPhone47inch)
    name = @"iPhone6";
else if(size == iPhone55inch)
    name = @"iPhone6Plus";
else
    name = @"iPad";


NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:@"gif"];
```

Comment: I will choose this as a right answer then, because when I load my video files, I will have to load them accordingly.

Thaank you for a precise answer.

Comment: May it be helpgul.^_^

Answer (score 1):

Try using specific image file names with appropriate naming conventions. Like,

```
     - fileName.png -> iPhone (non-retina/fallback)
     - fileName@2x.png -> iPhone (retina)
     - fileName@3x.png -> iPhone 6 Plus (retina)
     - fileName~ipad.png -> iPad (non-retina)
     - fileName@2x~ipad.png -> iPad (retina)

So, in code we can use:
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@”fileName” ofType:@”png”];
```

And internally `OS` will detect the device version and pick the respective image to showcase.

I have used this using storyboard image assigning, I have not tried with codebase, but you can give a try.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! I will see if it works, because the other problem is, say if I want the size of the video to be increased for iPhone 6 plus, do I have to use idiom for that. I think I will keep it constant.

Comment: I don't think you would require any naming convention for video file. It should be one file which works for all devices. Only thing is your video should be H.264 video, up to 1.5 Mbps. Still am not sure about video, but I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use uname from `sys/utsname.h` for getting device model.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108859/detect-the-specific-iphone-ipod-touch-model)

Comment: Thank you, I will look in to this. I think this the appropriate answer.