# How to prevent an iOS app from being installed and run on iPhone 4/4s?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I have an app with a very specific UI that doesn't fit screens with the 3:2 ratio, i.e. it is almost unusable on iPhone 4/4s for example.

Is there a way to prevent installations of my app on specific devices, namely iPhone 4/4s?

Comment: If it's an iPhone app and not a Universal app, then iPhone 4 size support is required, as Apple may test the app on an iPad Air in 1X or 2X mode and reject the app if it fails to run in the 3:2 display window.  Even if Metal is in the required capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

To exclude a certain device (eg. iPhone 4/4s) of the same type (eg. iPhone, iPad) there would need to be a [requirement](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1397/_index.html) in your app which will not run on that devices standard configuration.

An example would be if your app used the [Metal](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/MetalProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) Framework, which iPhone 4/4s doesn't support. If you've thought about targeting `armv7s`/`arm64` architectures exclusively (iPhone 4/4s use arm7) forget it — your app will be rejected.
↪︎ [Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH28-SW33)

If you're trying to exclude certain devices which are of the same type then you might have to dig deep into **[`UIRequiredDeviceCapabilites`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html)** and determine which key might eliminate the device your app doesn't support. Apple generally wants your app to support as many devices as possible, and apparently they expect it's interface to look good on all of them.

---

<strike>Set your `Deployment Target` to `iOS 8+`, since iPhone 4 is unable to run it.</strike>

<sub>EDIT: Unfortunately this doesn't exclude iPhone 4s</sub>

Comment: This is great for the iPhone 4, however the iPhone 4S, which can run iOS8+, has the same screen size as what the OP doesn't want to allow installs.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to prevent on specific devices since iOS 9 is supported by iPhone 4s. 
Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/29677597/4108415.