# iOS - Is OpenGL for 5- and Metal for 5s+ combination possible?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, metal

Topic is pretty much the question. I have OpenGL-based game with a lot of shaders. What I wanna do is convert it to Metal, so it can gain some perfomance from conversion, but I also want to have old devices support. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know for sure if that works but 
You could check  which iOS device is used 
[Detect the specific iPhone/iPod touch model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108859/detect-the-specific-iphone-ipod-touch-model)

And than execute the metal Code or the OpenGL es Code

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at **[MetalGL](https://metalgl.com)**. It is an implementation of *OpenGL ES* that runs on *Metal*. You write your app in *OpenGL ES*, and if *Metal* is available on the device, **MetalGL** will run the *OpenGL ES* code on *Metal* automatically, including shader conversion. If *Metal* is not available on the device, **MetalGL** will run the native *OpenGL ES* engine.

Depending on the nature of your app bottlenecks, your app may be more performant when running on *Metal*, and **MetalGL** can help you understand if and how your app will benefit from *Metal*, without you having to rewrite your app in *Metal*.

Full disclosure...I work on the **MetalGL** development team.

Comment: Hi, Bill!  I know you from cocos2d forums. What if I use cocos2d-objc 3.4.9, can it be applied to my app?

Comment: Hi Andrew. Actually, I believe that version of Cocos2D already supports Metal directly. But if not, MetalGL has been tested against Cocos2D 3.2 at least, so it shouldn't have any trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. I do it in a released game.
To test for Metal support on a device call:

```
// this returns NULL if the device does not support Metal
Class metalAvailable = NSClassFromString(@"CAMetalLayer");
```

Then take separate paths in your code to either initialise your Metal renderer or your OpenGL ES renderer. It's all pretty easy.