# Is there any way to get the iPhone Model number like(e.g. MC143C) through code

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I just figure out the device on which i'm working by the code given bellow:

```
NSString* deviceName()
{
    struct utsname systemInfo;
    uname(&systemInfo);
    return [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine
                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

But is there any way to find the model of my iPhone???
Example- iPhone 6 model number MG3C2
Thanks in advance ....

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108859/detect-the-specific-iphone-ipod-touch-model

Comment: Chandan - I want to findout the model of my iPhone??? Example- model number of iPhone 6 is MG3C2. Then I want to get MG3C2.