# How to identify a device (iPod touch/iPhone) is 2G or 3G?

Tags: ios

How to identify a device (iPod Touch/iPhone) is 2G or 3G?

Comment: Is this for the purpose of buying / programming against one ?

Comment: This is a duplicate of these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/786026/how-do-you-detect-iphone-v-iphone-3g-using-obj-c, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026277/distinguish-iphone-3g-from-iphone-3gs

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use Erica Sadun's UIDevice-Extension at:

http://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension/tree/master